# C#: Initialising member variables to be exposed via properties

Tags: c#

I have just written a small piece of code and it struck me that I am not sure what method of initialisation is best practice when it comes to initialising my member variables which will be exposed and used via properties. Which is the best way to initialise my member variables out of the two examples below and more importantly **why**?

**Example 1:**

```
    private string m_connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationDefault"].ConnectionString;
    private string m_providerName = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationDefault"].ProviderName;

    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get { return m_connectionString; }
        set { m_connectionString = value; }
    }

    public string ProviderName
    {
        get { return m_providerName; }
        set { m_providerName = value; }
    }

    public EntityClusterRefreshServiceDatabaseWorker()
    {
    }
```

**Example 2:**

```
    private string m_connectionString;
    private string m_providerName;

    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get { return m_connectionString; }
        set { m_connectionString = value; }
    }

    public string ProviderName
    {
        get { return m_providerName; }
        set { m_providerName = value; }
    }

    public EntityClusterRefreshServiceDatabaseWorker()
    {
        ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationDefault"].ConnectionString;
        ProviderName = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationDefault"].ProviderName;
    }
```

NOTE: Assume that I am not using these variables in a static context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It really doesn't matter which of those you use, except in the very odd situation where a base class constructor calls an overridden member, in which case the timing would change: instance variable initializers are run *before* the base class constructor call, whereas obviously the constructor body is executed afterwards.

In the latter case, you can make your code a lot simpler though using [automatically implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx):

```
public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
public string ProviderName { get; set; }

public EntityClusterRefreshServiceDatabaseWorker()
{
    // Code as before
    ConnectionString = ...;
    ProviderName = ...;
}
```

You can't do this with the first form, as automatically implemented properties don't have any way of specifying an initial value.

(You may *also* want to consider making the setters private, but that's a separate concern.)

Comment: I see. Is it strictly necessary to use auto properties? I prefer to use the longer winded way of doing it for clarity and in case of eventualities like you just pointed out that I wasnt aware of but is there any benefit other than reducing lines of code and possibly minor readability?

Comment: @CSharpened reducing lines of code and increasing readability are reason enough ;p

Comment: @CSharpened: No, it's not strictly necessary - it just makes your code shorter and clearer. I fail to see how the longer version is *clearer* than the short version - there's a lot more room for typos etc, and it clutters up your genuine *logic* with trivialities.

Comment: Ok. By making the setters private do I make sure that these properties can only be used withing this class then? In terms of ensuring nothing breaks in future would it not be wise to use the implementation less likely to cause errors like in the example that you gave? So that if I use the example 1 implementation I avoid possible future problems if the constructor does end up calling an overridden member?

Comment: @CSharpened: Constructors calling virtual members are asking for problems anyway. I'd suggest using the automatically implemented version and simply avoiding the smell of the virtual call. I would say you're more likely to end up with errors due to cut and paste of "full" properties than to come across that particular issue - I just mentioned it for completeness. And yes, by making the setters private you stop other classes from setting those properties. (Nested classes within this class can still do so though.) One more point about auto-implemented properties: you can always change later.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Much appreciated and very well explained as always.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially doing the same thing but writing it in a different form.

I always prefer (and use) the second aprroach because I don't like methods being executed in the middle of nowhere. It's better to split things. Attributes are declared on class body and initialized on class constructor.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the connection strings are not supposed to be changed, you can initialize them as `static readonly`:

```
private readonly static string m_connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationDefault"].ConnectionString;
private readonly static string m_providerName = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationDefault"].ProviderName;
```

readonly variables are allowed to be initialized only in class declaration/contructor and are better optimized for performance than regular private variables.

And back on the question - it really doesn't matter where you'll initialize these.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the fields and go for automatic properties & make your setters private.

```
public string ConnectionString {get; private set;}

public string ProviderName {get; private set;}
```

Rob